# @fortawesome/react-fontawesome icons not resizing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, font-awesome, react-font-awesome

I am using the version 5.12.1 and suddenly applying style to the component like this...

```
<section className="container-center">
    <FontAwesomeIcon icon="arrow-down" style={{ color: "var(--themeP)", style={{ fontSize: "1.5rem" }} }} />
</section>
```

...is no longer working.

I am using this in another project with the exactly same version and that is working fine. I noticed that is applied automatically a `fa-w-14` className but this class is not actually being applied and making the icons being displayed very huge without style.

The only solution I came across was `transform: scale(x)` when x is the value of size. But that is not what I want since it takes all the space where it meant to be filled in the original size.

I tried insert the prop `size` from docs without any result, too.

My `package.json` related font-awesome modules are like these:

```
"@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.27",
"@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.12.1",
"@fortawesome/react-fontawesome": "^0.1.9"
```

Only using the solid icon.
If someone can shed some light on this, I`d appreciate the support.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was mind-bendingly simple by just changing `fontSize` to `width` instead. I double-checked my workable fontawesome icons project and I used to declare `fontSize`.

Answer (score 0):

You should import the fontawesome style file in your app as below

```
import "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core/styles.css";
```

This will make the icon to be equal to your body font-sizeand  let you use or add the default size prop values like *2xs, xs, sm, lg, xl, 2xl*. In your case

```
<section className="container-center">
    <FontAwesomeIcon icon="arrow-down" size="sm" style={{ color: "var(--themeP)" }} />
</section>
```